# How to handle the right to be forgotten

Tags: support

So, basically I just joined a community and posted some stuffs there.
Then I wanted my nickname to be different on that community, since one is "professional" and the other is more "personal" oriented.

The thing is, someone commented my answer and greeted me using my old nickname. When I asked if this person could edit his comment, it was not possible for him to do so after more of 5min.

Here is a link for your understanding : [my first post on World Building](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25427/vertical-city-why-build-it/25431#25431)

My question are :

Is it possible for someone in the community to edit comments ?

How could I notify someone that my privacy has been "hurt" and take action to restore it?

Comment: Moderators can edit comments (flag the comment as "other" and explain why you want it edited). The original commenter could always delete the comment entirely.

Comment: In that particular case, just flag the comments as too chatty. Two such flags ensure deletion.